# $\mathbb{R} ^{\mathbb{N}}$ with box topology is not first countable

Tags: general-topology

I have $X:=\mathbb{R} ^{\mathbb{N}}$ equipped with the box topology. I want to show that it's not first countable: since every coordinate has a countable basis for its neighbourhoods, and not less (in $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology) then a neighbourhood  of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ must have a basis of cardinality at least $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$. Is this correct?
Moreover I have to show the following. Let $I$ be the set of the sequences converging to $0$ but never $0$: then there's no sequence in $I$ converging to it. Find a net in $I$ converging to it.
I know that if my proof about the first countability is true then a sequence can't converge to $(0)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ because it would make a countable basis for the neighbourhoods of $0$.

Is everything correct? Can you fin a net in $I$ converging to $(0)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Well... not to be pedantic... actually, to be pedantic this is a mathematics website... every constant sequence is convergent. :-)

Comment: of course.. I meant a sequence and a net in $I$.. edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequences that are eventually constant are convergent, so in every space each point is the limit of a convergent sequence. What you mean, I suspect, is that no point is the limit of a sequence of *other* points. Showing this would indeed show that $X$ is not first countable, but in fact it’s not true here. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $x^{(n)}=\langle x_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where

$$x_k^{(n)}=\begin{cases}
n,&\text{if }k=0\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

It’s easy to check that $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to the zero sequence $z=\langle 0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$ in $X$, even though each $x^{(n)}\in X\setminus\{z\}$.

However, it’s possible to show directly that $X$ is not first countable. Your cardinality argument is not sufficient as it stands: it shows that each point of $X$ has a local base of cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}=2^\omega$, but you would need further argument to establish that no smaller local base exists.

> **Added:** In fact it’s consistent with the usual axioms of set theory that $2^\omega=\omega_2$, and each point of $X$ has a local base of cardinality $\omega_1$: this is the case in models in which the [*dominating number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum#Bounding_number_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-00000015-QINU.60.22.27.7F_and_dominating_number_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-00000016-QINU.60.22.27.7F) $\mathfrak{d}=\omega_1$ and the continuum $\mathfrak{c}=\omega_2$.

In the second half of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1398893/12042) I used this approach to show a more general result:

> For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $X_n$ be a first countable space with a non-isolated point $p_n$. Let $X$ be the box product of the spaces $X_n$, and let $p=\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in X$; then $X$ is not first countable at $p$.

Since no point of $\Bbb R$ is isolated, this shows that $X$ is not first countable at any point. You might find it instructive to try to adapt that argument to the specific case of the space $X$.

If $Y$ is any space, and $p\in Y$ is not an isolated point, we can always find a net in $Y\setminus\{p\}$ that converges to $p$. I’ll do this in general and let you adapt that to the specific case in your problem.

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be any nbhd base at $p$, and let $\mathscr{D}=\{\langle B,x\rangle:x\in B\setminus\{p\}\in\mathscr{B}\}$. For $\langle B,x\rangle,\langle C,y\rangle\in\mathscr{D}$ let $\langle B,x\rangle\preceq\langle C,y\rangle$ if and only if $B\supseteq C$; then $\langle\mathscr{D},\preceq\rangle$ is a directed set. (Check this!) Let $\nu$ be the net

$$\nu:\mathscr{D}\to Y:\langle B,x\rangle\mapsto x\;;$$

I leave it to you to verify that $\nu$ converges to $p$.

Comment: Great! Just a question.. maybe I explained badly.. what I meant is that EVERY base of a nbhd of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ must be at least countable and that then EVERY base of the nbhd of the sequence $0$, being the product of bases of every term, must have at least cardinality $\aleph_0$. Is it wrong anyway?

Comment: @Nicolò: Yes: for the argument to work, you’d have to show that every local base actually is the product of of local bases on the factor spaces, and that’s not immediately evident.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way to do this is to use a diagonalization argument.

Suppose $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ in the box topology is first countable and wlog $x=0$. Then if $\mathscr{N}=\left \{ (U^{(n)})_{m} \right \}_{m,n}$, and we list the elements of $\mathscr N$in the usual way, we may observe that $\frac{1}{2}U_{n}^{(n)}$ is open, contains $0$ but contains no member of $\mathscr N$, so $\mathscr N$ can not be a nbhd base about $0$.

Similarly, let $x_{m}$ be any sequence in $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ such that $x_m$ is $not$ eventually constant.

Then for $x_1$, choose $x^{n_1}_{1}\neq 0$ and in general, for $x_m\ $ an $x^{n_m}_{m}\neq 0$ such that $m>k\Rightarrow n_m>n_k$. This is possible since $x_m$ is not eventually constant. Now if we take the open set $U=\left ( -\frac{1}{2}x^{m_k}_{k}, \frac{1}{2}x^{m_k}_{k}\right )\cup (-1,1)_{n\neq m_k}$ we see that $U$ contains $no$  member of the sequence $x_m$ so $x_m\nrightarrow0$.

If $x_m$ is eventually constant then there is an integer $N$ such that if $n>N$ there are only finitely many non-zero coordinates $x^{(k)}_{n}$ in $x_n$ and it is easy to show that in this case $x_m\to 0$.

Finding a net converging to zero has already been covered in the other answer.